# Trying to pass event from Parent to Child not working. Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

The accordion is the parent component and the child component houses the data therefore I need to know when the parent was updateExpanded(clicked) so that I can call the api. this is to minimize the number of api calls.

I've tried quite a few thing with EventEmitters but it doesn't work the way I want to to. The event fires the whole time even when the parent hasn't been click. The eventemitter makes me think it should only be used to fire an event in the parent from the child. So don't think I am using it right.

Now, I am using @ViewChild to actually access the childs method to fire it. This is working fine but I do get Circular Dependency warnings which also isn't good.

Parent: => PlannedMaintenanceComponent

```
@ViewChild(forwardRef(() => PlannedMaintenanceDetailComponent), { static: false })
private plannedMaintenanceDetailComponent: PlannedMaintenanceDetailComponent;

updateExpanded(id: string) {

    this.plannedMaintenanceDetailComponent.parentIsExpanded(this.isExpanded, id);
}
```

Child: => PlannedMaintenanceDetailComponent

```
 public parentIsExpanded(isExpanded: boolean, id: string) {
    this.plannedMaintenanceId = id;
    //call api
  }
```

How do I fire an event in the child component when someone clicks on the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an `EventEmitter` int the `PlannedMaintenanceDetailComponent` so you can subscribe to it in the parent component executing a callback when this EventEmitter emits.

```
export class PlannedMaintenanceDetailComponent {
 isDropped: boolean;
 isDroppedEvent= new EventEmitter<boolean>()
 //..

 onClick() {
   this.isDropped = !isDropped() ;
   isDroppedEvent.emit(isDropped);
 }
}
```

then in the parent class

```
private plannedMaintenanceDetailComponent: PlannedMaintenanceDetailComponent;
ngOnInit() {
  plannedMaintenanceDetailComponent.isDroppedEvent.subscribe((isDropped) => {
   if (isDropped){
    call my api
   }
 })    
}
```

Comment: Ah, I never subscribed to the event. Thank you. I am going to give this a go later today.

Comment: I have noticed one thing I would like to expand on. The parent component has the accordion. when it expands it needs to send the event to the child. the child needs to call api and not the parent. (The child lives as an accordion item and shows data when parent expanded)

Comment: you can model that behaviour too: create a dropDown event `dropDownEvent` emitter on the parent, and then pass it down to the child, you may use `@Input() dropEmitter: EventEmitter(boolean)` on the child and `<app-child-componet [dropEmitter]=dropDownEvent></app-child-component>` on the parent. With that you can subscribe to it and execute your api call on the callback function on the child

Comment: Brilliant. much appreciated.

Comment: I implemented this, the weird thing is that the event fires 4 times. (i checked with a simple console log). I implemented this in the child `@Input()
  expandedEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>();` and then this on ngOnInit => `this.expandedEventEmitter.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })`

Comment: are you subscribing more than once? assign `this.subscription = expanded.subscribe(...) ` you might need to implement `ngOnDestroy()` in your child component and unsubscribe within it with `expanded. unsubscribe()`